# Insert working hours into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, insert

I am triying to insert mothly working hours with PHP and MySQL (only on weekdays) at once.

> From : 01.02.2013 08:30
>   To :  28.02.2013  17:30

Then it should insert for each business day until 28.02.2013 such

> 01.02.2013 08:30 -01.02.2013 17:30
>   02.02.2013 08:30 -02.02.2013 17:30
>   03.02.2013 08:30 -03.02.2013 17:30
>   ...

Could you please help with some hints where to start?

I am inserting with following code only a date..

```
$startDate = $rsnew["starttime"];  
$endDate =  $rsnew["endtime"];      

// Convert to UNIX timestamps                          
$currentTime = strtotime($startDate);
$endTime = strtotime($endDate);

// Loop until we reach the last day
$result = array();                          
while ($currentTime <= $endTime) {
    if (date('N', $currentTime) < 6) {
        $result[] = date('Y-m-d', $currentTime);
    }
    $currentTime = strtotime('+1 day', $currentTime);
    echo "Hallo" .$currentTime;   
}  

// start insertion        
foreach($result as $value)        
{
    $MyResult = ew_Execute("INSERT INTO dates (date) VALUES ('".$value."')");
    echo "Hallo" .$value;                                                         
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need this anymore but here's a simple way to do this that also very efficient:

```
$start    = new DateTime('2013-02-01');
$finish   = (new DateTime('2013-02-28'))->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $finish);
$dates    = array();

foreach ($period as $dt) {
    $dates[] = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
}

$MyResult = ew_Execute("INSERT INTO dates (date) VALUES ('" . implode("'),('", $dates) . "')");
```

Here's what this is doing:

1. Create [**DateTime**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects for our start date and end date (We have to add one day to our end date as the loop we create below will not include the last day).
2. Create a [**DateInterval**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object that represents how much we want to increment our DateTimes by when we loop through them (1 day).
3. Create a [**DatePeriod**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object that allows us to loop through the dates we want.
4. Create an empty array to store the dates we will later add to the database.
5. Loop through the dates between the starting date and ending date adding the dates to our array.
6. Use [**`implode()`**](https://www.php.net/function.implode) to create one query instead of [*num days*] queries which is faster to execute.